# Condition doesn't return true when it should

Tags: c#, linq, conditional-statements, where-clause

I've got the following method:

```
public static List<string> GetArgsListStartsWith(string filter, bool invertSelection, bool lowercaseArgs)
{
    return GetArgumentsList(lowercaseArgs)
          .Where(x => !invertSelection && x.StartsWith(filter)).ToList();
}
```

And then I call it like this `GetArgsListStartsWith("/", true, false)`

That would translate to: get a list of all arguments that do not start with "/".
The problem is that the list doesn't get populated, even if all arguments do not start with "/".

If I call `GetArgsListStartsWith("/", false, false)` which translates to: get a list of all arguments which start with "/", the list does get populated with the arguments that start with "/".

I suspect that `!invertSelection && x.StartsWith(filter)` doesn't return `true` when `invertSelection` is set to true and `x.StartsWith(filter)` returns false, but I do not understand why. Does anyone see something I don't?

Comment: having invertSelection = false you are saying GetArgumentsList(lowercaseArgs).Where(x => false && someBoolValue) that is always false

Comment: Yes... I don't know what I was thinking of when I thought false && false returns true. I should get a break. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As other answers have said, your condition will only *ever* return true when `invertSelection` is false.

The simplest way of conditionally inverting a result is to use the [XOR operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zkacc7k1):

```
.Where(x => x.StartsWith(filter) ^ invertSelection)
```

I prefer this over lc's solution as it only specifies the `StartsWith` once.

Comment: This is somewhat harder to read than `!invertSelection ==  x.StartsWith(filter)`. And using bitwise operations on boolean values isn't necessarily nice, could use `!=`.

Comment: @Qnan: For you, maybe :) Personally I prefer this - or potentially `invertSelection != x.StartsWith(filter)`. Inverting and then using normal equality is too much for my brain...

Comment: +1 Yes this is better. For some reason my brain kept thinking `*-1` and just didn't click.

Comment: @Qnan - `^` with boolean operands is _not_ a bitwise operation. Common misconception.

Comment: Thank you both. Besides making a stupid beginner's mistake, I also learnt a new way to check if an expression evaluates to false or true.

Answer (score 7):

```
.Where(x => invertSelection ? !x.StartsWith(filter) : x.StartsWith(filter))
```

Comment: Heh, shame it won't let you correct the typo because the edit is too small.

Comment: or just use `==` instead of `&&`

Answer (score 2):

The value of !invertSelection && x.StartsWith(filter) where invertSelection = true is always false.